# freeze in purple screen after login.

Tags: boot

Most of instances I try to boot Ubuntu 16.10, it freezes in a purple screen after login. No chance to load a terminal with any key combinations. Only chance is to press the power switch. Wifi led blinks as if there is any activity. 64bits OS core2duo processor 3GB ram i915 intel graphics.

Comment: Have you tried opening terminal before login, and restarting/reconfiguring lightdm from there and then logging in?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but itś still with the same problem.. I need to reboot several times and then the graphical desktop loads.... thank you brndn2k

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem. My solution:

- boot using "nomodeset" kernel option
- install kernel 4.10.6 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.6/
- install missing firmware (kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin, bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin)  from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware
- reboot and enjoy

Hope this helps.